# iOS Stuck in boot loop — What is the biggest file on the system which also happens to brick the phone if deleted?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, error

I regularly optimize the file storage of my iPhone, (iOS 14.3, unc0ver), and this time around, I deleted a file I thought was analogous with a Windows cache file of a couple gigabytes that normally is recreated if you delete it. I remember that the file name included the words "cache", undescores, and "arm" or "arm64" among 2-4 other words. I want to say the file type was .dll, but I feel like there is a great probability that I am just misremembering this part. The file was the largest file in the system by far with ca. 2.9 gigabytes.

Once deleted in Filza, I noticed the phone continued operating, and the app did not crash—this convinced me that I deleted something likely analogous to the cache file on Windows, or worst case scenario, something that is not necessary for operation — also supported by the fact that the modifying date was January 1, 2020 making me think it is some data debris.

Once confident, I deleted the file from the trash in Filza—and, of course, that was fatal. Minutes later I tried to initialize an app that had not been running before the failure, and no it wouldn't start. I tried again with other apps to no avail.

I knew I cannot retrieve the file, and I still was fairly convcinced that even if it was an operative cache file like on Windows, it would symply be recreated from the OS on reboot.

And that's since when the phone has been in bootloop for hours by the time I am posting this.

1. What file fits the above description as this could help addressing this issue?
2. If there is no hit for the first question, one way to identify it is by looking at what is the biggest file on the OS (non-media file) on a jailbroken iPhone hence this question: What is the biggest file on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

The files name is "dyld_shared_cache_arm64", "of all the things you could delete, this would be the worst. It would be as close to delete system32 as you could possibly get on an iDevice." (comment by Beta382 at [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/2hbiz1/comment/ckr8tmn/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3))

"Since iPhoneOS 3.1, all default (private and public) libraries have been combined into a big cache file to improve performance in `/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/dyld_shared_cache_armX`, where X can be:

X   Device ARM Architecture

- v6    ARMv6
- v7    ARMv7
- v7s   ARMv7
- 64    ARMv8" (comment by prof1t at [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/2hbiz1/comment/ckr4h1z/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3))

"As of iOS 13.5 application code is now in frameworks in the shared cache. The binaries you see in `/Applications` or `/private/var/staged_system_apps` are now just shims, so if you attempt to class-dump them it will error out as no ObjC section will be found." (http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Dyld_shared_cache)